# How can I find application start time on iOS?

Tags: ios, vuforia

We are using Qualcomm's Vuforia API for doing AR on iOS.  It reports timestamps relative to the start of the application:

> double com.qualcomm.vuforia.Frame.getTimeStamp    (   )
>   A time stamp that defines when the original camera image was shot
>   Value in seconds representing the offset to application startup time.
>   Independent from image creation the time stamp always refers to the time
>   the camera image was shot.

Other things report relative to system boot time (Motion API) or since a fixed reference date.  I need to get these all relative to the same offset, which means I need to know when the app started in one of these other time frames.

Any pointers much appreciated.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: interesting. I can't figure it out either... I searched the docs and headers... could it be they use the time when you FIRST access the TrackerManager?!

Comment: I don't know. It may actually be their documentation is wrong.  We're looking to see if they are actually using the time since device boot.

Answer (score 0):

**DICLAIMER: I don't know what vuforia is**

this will give you the current time.  you can run this at the start of your app.

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
```

if you want the seconds between this and another event, you can do this

```
NSLog(@"%f seconds have elapsed since start", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]);
```

Comment: That's what we've been doing.  But, that's not exactly correct:  that's giving me the start time since "some time kinda close to app start time", which will be slightly different than whatever Vuforia is using.  Perhaps this is what they are doing (which would be a bad choice by them), it which case we're screwed.  We need to run computations that assume all the time stamps are in the same reference frame, not one that "sort of close", otherwise there will be error and jitter.

Comment: Sorry, I probably can't help further without knowing anything about vuforia.. =/

Comment: I appreciate the attempt! :)   

Vuforia is an Augmented Reality API (follow the vuforia tag for pointers, or look at developer.vuforia.com).  The essential bit of info is that they provide time stamped video frames from the camera (it's cross platform, so they take care of the camera), and the tracking information (what stuff they find in the video frame) is marked with the time stamp of the video frame.  I need to figure out how to convert from their time stamps to something more common.

Answer (score 0):

### JUST read the comments so this won't help at all :)

Here is a code example that shows the times

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property(assign) NSTimeInterval bootTimestamp;
@property(assign) NSTimeInterval startTimestamp;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

NSTimeInterval GetBootTimestamp() {
#define MIB_SIZE 2
    int mib[MIB_SIZE];
    size_t size;
    struct timeval  boottime;
    
    mib[0] = CTL_KERN;
    mib[1] = KERN_BOOTTIME;
    size = sizeof(boottime);
    if (sysctl(mib, MIB_SIZE, &boottime, &size, NULL, 0) != -1)
    {
        // successful call
        return boottime.tv_sec + boottime.tv_usec / 1.e6;
    }
    
    return -1;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.bootTimestamp = GetBootTimestamp(); //secs
    self.startTimestamp = [NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970;
    
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self laterEvent];
    });
    return YES;
}

- (void)laterEvent {
    NSTimeInterval eventTimestamp = [NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970;
    NSLog(@"%lf s after start of app", eventTimestamp-self.startTimestamp);
    NSLog(@"%lf s after boot of device", eventTimestamp-self.bootTimestamp);
}

@end
```